# javascript missing ; after for-loop initializer (unknown source

Tags: javascript

The following code is my javascript that i am trying to run(without the imports or initial variable declarations i.e. imported functions used and variables like triggerStatus shown below were already declared but not pasted).  The error that i get when it runs is `Error Running Script [scriptToRun.js]:com.sun.phobos.script.util.ExtendedScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: missing ; after for-loop initializer (<Unknown source>#49) in <Unknown source> at line number 49`

```
function runScript() {
  let (survey = newDocument,
    statusQuery = new AeSpcsrvySDTO()) {
    logger.fine('Space survey [' + survey.spaceSurvey + ']');
    // Look up the status
    statusQuery.statusCode = survey.statusCode;
    let (statuses = new StatusServiceImpl(SystemContext.getInstance()).findByDTO(statusQuery, null)) {
      let (status = statuses.get(0)) {
        logger.fine('Space survey [' + survey.spaceSurvey + ']'
                      + ' status [' + survey.statusCode + ']'
                      + ' completeYn [' + AeSpcsrvySCompleteYN.valueOfFromCode(status.completeYn).name() + ']');
        if (status.completeYn != triggerStatus.code) {
          logger.fine('Ignoring space survey [' + survey.spaceSurvey + ']');
          return;
        }
        logger.fine('Space survey [' + survey.spaceSurvey + ']'
                      + ' has ' + survey.aeSpcsrvyLocDTOList.size() + ' locations');
        for (let location in Iterator(survey.aeSpcsrvyLocDTOList)) {
          logger.fine('Space survey [' + location.spaceSurvey + ']'
                        + ' region [' + location.regionCode + ']'
                        + ' facility [' + location.facId + ']'
                        + ' property [' + location.bldg + ']'
                        + ' location [' + location.locId + ']');
          let (highestUsagePercent = BigDecimal.ZERO,
               highestUsage = null) {
            for (let occupancy in Iterator(location.aeSpcsrvyOccDTOList)) {
              logger.fine('Space survey [' + occupancy.spaceSurvey + ']'
                            + ' region [' + occupancy.regionCode + ']'
                            + ' facility [' + occupancy.facId + ']'
                            + ' property [' + occupancy.bldg + ']'
                            + ' location [' + occupancy.locId + ']'
                            + ' seq [' + occupancy.seq + ']'
                            + ' percent [' + occupancy.percentOccupancy + ']');
              let (proration = occupancy.percentOccupancy.movePointLeft(2)) {
                for (let usage in Iterator(occupancy.aeSpcsrvyOccUsgDTOList)) {
                  logger.fine('Space survey [' + usage.spaceSurvey + ']'
                                + ' region [' + usage.regionCode + ']'
                                + ' facility [' + usage.facId + ']'
                                + ' property [' + usage.bldg + ']'
                                + ' location [' + usage.locId + ']'
                                + ' seq [' + usage.seq + ']'
                                + ' sub seq [' + usage.subSeq + ']'
                                + ' usage code [' + usage.usageCode + ']'
                                + ' percent [' + usage.usagePercent + ']');
                  if (usage.usageCode && usage.usagePercent
                    // There's a validation for <= 100, but not for > 0.
                    && usage.usagePercent.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) > 0) {
                    let (proratedUsagePercent = usage.usagePercent.multiply(proration)) {
                      if (proratedUsagePercent.compareTo(highestUsagePercent) > 0
                        || (proratedUsagePercent.compareTo(highestUsagePercent) == 0
                        && usage.usageCode.compareTo(highestUsage.usageCode) < 0)) {
                        highestUsage = usage;
                        highestUsagePercent = proratedUsagePercent;
                        logger.fine('New highest usage percent is [' + highestUsagePercent + ']');
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
            if (highestUsage) {
              // Look up the location and update the usage.
              let (locationKey = new AeBLocDPK(highestUsage.regionCode, highestUsage.facId,
                                               highestUsage.bldg, highestUsage.locId),
                   serviceImpl = new PropertyServiceImpl(SystemContext.getInstance())) {
                let (location = serviceImpl.findByPrimaryKey(locationKey, false)) {
                  location.usageCode = highestUsage.usageCode;
                  serviceImpl.save(location, false, false);
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Looking at the specified line 49 and surrounding for loop syntax, i do not see the issue, am i missing something?

thanks

**update**
changes using AP.'s suggestions i get a new error: current code(error line 3: Missing ; before statement):

```
function runScript() {
    'use strict';
    let survey = newDocument,
        statusQuery = new AeSpcsrvySDTO();
    logger.fine('Space survey [' + survey.spaceSurvey + ']');
    // Look up the status
    statusQuery.statusCode = survey.statusCode;
    let statuses = new StatusServiceImpl(SystemContext.getInstance()).findByDTO(statusQuery, null);
    let status = statuses.get(0);
    logger.fine('Space survey [' + survey.spaceSurvey + ']' +
        ' status [' + survey.statusCode + ']' +
        ' completeYn [' + AeSpcsrvySCompleteYN.valueOfFromCode(status.completeYn).name() + ']');
    if (status.completeYn != triggerStatus.code) {
        logger.fine('Ignoring space survey [' + survey.spaceSurvey + ']');
        return;
    }
    logger.fine('Space survey [' + survey.spaceSurvey + ']' +
        ' has ' + survey.aeSpcsrvyLocDTOList.size() + ' locations');
    for (let location in Iterator(survey.aeSpcsrvyLocDTOList)) {
        logger.fine('Space survey [' + location.spaceSurvey + ']' +
            ' region [' + location.regionCode + ']' +
            ' facility [' + location.facId + ']' +
            ' property [' + location.bldg + ']' +
            ' location [' + location.locId + ']');
        let highestUsagePercent = BigDecimal.ZERO,
            highestUsage = null;
        for (let occupancy in Iterator(location.aeSpcsrvyOccDTOList)) {
            logger.fine('Space survey [' + occupancy.spaceSurvey + ']' +
                ' region [' + occupancy.regionCode + ']' +
                ' facility [' + occupancy.facId + ']' +
                ' property [' + occupancy.bldg + ']' +
                ' location [' + occupancy.locId + ']' +
                ' seq [' + occupancy.seq + ']' +
                ' percent [' + occupancy.percentOccupancy + ']');
            let proration = occupancy.percentOccupancy.movePointLeft(2);
            for (let usage in Iterator(occupancy.aeSpcsrvyOccUsgDTOList)) {
                logger.fine('Space survey [' + usage.spaceSurvey + ']' +
                    ' region [' + usage.regionCode + ']' +
                    ' facility [' + usage.facId + ']' +
                    ' property [' + usage.bldg + ']' +
                    ' location [' + usage.locId + ']' +
                    ' seq [' + usage.seq + ']' +
                    ' sub seq [' + usage.subSeq + ']' +
                    ' usage code [' + usage.usageCode + ']' +
                    ' percent [' + usage.usagePercent + ']');
                if (usage.usageCode && usage.usagePercent
                    // There's a validation for <= 100, but not for > 0.
                    &&
                    usage.usagePercent.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) > 0) {
                    let proratedUsagePercent = usage.usagePercent.multiply(proration);
                    if (proratedUsagePercent.compareTo(highestUsagePercent) > 0 ||
                        (proratedUsagePercent.compareTo(highestUsagePercent) == 0 &&
                            usage.usageCode.compareTo(highestUsage.usageCode) < 0)) {
                        highestUsage = usage;
                        highestUsagePercent = proratedUsagePercent;
                        logger.fine('New highest usage percent is [' + highestUsagePercent + ']');
                    }

                }
            }

        }
        if (highestUsage) {
            // Look up the location and update the usage.
            let locationKey = new AeBLocDPK(highestUsage.regionCode, highestUsage.facId, highestUsage.bldg, highestUsage.locId),
                serviceImpl = new PropertyServiceImpl(SystemContext.getInstance());
            let location = serviceImpl.findByPrimaryKey(locationKey, false);
            location.usageCode = highestUsage.usageCode;
            serviceImpl.save(location, false, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could consider using **`.forEach`** like `survey.aeSpcsrvyLocDTOList.forEach(element => {do something;})`

Comment: Could you format your code with: http://jsbeautifier.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve with this block:

```
 let (proratedUsagePercent = usage.usagePercent.multiply(proration)) {
                      if (proratedUsagePercent.compareTo(highestUsagePercent) > 0
                        || (proratedUsagePercent.compareTo(highestUsagePercent) == 0
                        && usage.usageCode.compareTo(highestUsage.usageCode) < 0)) {
                        highestUsage = usage;
                        highestUsagePercent = proratedUsagePercent;
                        logger.fine('New highest usage percent is [' + highestUsagePercent + ']');
                      }
                    }
```

You cannot add a block in front of a `let expression`, maybe change that to:

```
let proratedUsagePercent = usage.usagePercent.multiply(proration)
if (proratedUsagePercent.compareTo(highestUsagePercent) > 0
                    || (proratedUsagePercent.compareTo(highestUsagePercent) == 0
                    && usage.usageCode.compareTo(highestUsage.usageCode) < 0)) {
                    highestUsage = usage;
                    highestUsagePercent = proratedUsagePercent;
                    logger.fine('New highest usage percent is [' + highestUsagePercent + ']');
                  }
```

**Also:** Maybe your browser may not support a `let declaration` outside `strict mode`. Replace it with `var` or add `'use strict;'` (with the quotes) to the top of your function.

Comment: Trying AP.'s suggestions my error message moved up to line 29: 

missing ; before statement (<Unknown source>#29) in <Unknown source> at line number 29

and i thought it might be the same issue as the one you pointed out with the cannot add a block in front of a let expression so i tried something similar at the line 29 block

Comment: I see `+ ' facility [' + occupancy.facId + ']'` on line 29

Comment: oh sorry forgot to convert the line number, it would be line 2 in the code above: let (survey = newDocument,
    statusQuery = new AeSpcsrvySDTO()) {

Comment: Yeah that's going to become: `let survey = newDocument, statusQuery = new AeSpcsrvySDTO()`
And the stuff in `{}` on a new line, without the `{}`

Comment: after changing that line and trying a few other things, i still get the new error of the `missing ; before statement on that line 2` above, both with and without the { } i tried even adding the semi colon to the end of that let statement

Comment: `let statuses = new StatusServiceImpl(SystemContext.getInstance()).findByDTO(statusQuery, null) {` That's also incorrect, I feel you shoould go through all your let statements once again, and fix the syntax you're using `let <set expression> <invalid block statement>` to having the block just be regular code after the `let expression`

Comment: i went through the code and changed all of the let statements to match, also updated the second set of code above so you can see what i have done so far.  still get the `Missing ; Before statement on line 3` error.  i feel like i'm missing something small i'm just not seeing it, thanks for your help

Comment: Can't figure out any more locations where the code could be going wrong, I'd suggest using `console.logs()` to figure out where the errors are being thrown. Or even removing parts of the code, till it works, and then re-introduce them back in to find the faulty component.